# pandas update dataframe with complex where condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to process daily data for bank clients. Sample data for two clients is loaded into df dataframe.

I need to process each client separately and need to iterate day after day, for rolling balance and retaining data, so I create index on account_id + bus_dt and sort df by this index.
I need to calculate date and balance differences between rows, so I need previous row values.

For each account for the first row I need to reset all values to specific values so I use `cumcount()` function to create sequence number in each group.

I am able to update all rows in df where sequence=0, however I cannot update rows where sequence>0 and other criteria is required:
I can access selected row with first part of where condition:

```
df.loc[df['seq'] > 0 , 'balance']
```

I can access selected row with second part of where condition:

```
df.loc[df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days') , 'balance']
```

But I cannot access desired rows with both criterias at once:

```
df.loc[(df['seq'] > 0 and df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days')) , 'balance']
```

with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Ludwik\Python\python-3.5.4rc1-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 955, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I use where A > 0 **and** B = whatever?

Below is full code to prepare data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# np.array([3] * 4 + [4] * 5 ,dtype='int32')
# dates = np.array(pd.date_range('20170101', periods=6) + pd.date_range('20170101', periods=5) )

df1=pd.DataFrame({
'account_id': np.array([101] * 7,dtype='int32'),
'bus_dt': pd.date_range('20170101', periods=7),
'balance': abs(np.random.randn(7)*100)
})
df2=pd.DataFrame({
'account_id': np.array([102] * 10,dtype='int32'),
'bus_dt': pd.date_range('20170104', periods=10),
'balance': abs(np.random.randn(10)*100)
})

df1=df1.loc[df1['bus_dt'] != '20170103']
df1=df1.loc[df1['bus_dt'] != '20170104']

df2=df2.loc[df2['bus_dt'] != '20170111']
df2=df2.loc[df2['bus_dt'] != '20170112']

df=df1.append(df2)



df.head()

# i need to process each account separately and need to iterate day after day, for rolling and retaining data,
# so i create index on account_id and bus_dt and sort df by this index
df.set_index(['account_id','bus_dt'], inplace=True, drop=False)
df.sort_index(ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)

# i need to calculate date differences between rows, so i need prev row values
df['prev_bus_dt']=df.groupby(level=0)['bus_dt'].shift(1)
df['prev_balance']=df.groupby(level=0)['balance'].shift(1)

#i need to zero first row in each group, so i create sequence in each group to access 0 indexed row in each group
df['seq']=df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
# so I update
df.loc[df['seq'] == 0, 'prev_bus_dt'] = df['bus_dt']
df.loc[df['seq'] == 0, 'prev_balance'] = df['balance']
```

Below is the piece of work I struggle with. How can I perform upate on all rows of dataframe that meet beow criteria?

```
# but when I need to update selected column based on complex where criteria, here starts the problem:
# all of the below methods do not work
# option 1
df.loc[df['seq'] > 0 and df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days'), 'balance']=max(df['prev_balance'] - df['balance'],0)
# option 2
df['balance']=np.where(df['seq'] > 0 and df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days'), max(df['prev_balance'] - df['balance'],0), 0)
# option 3
df.loc[df['seq'] > 0 and df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days'),'balance'].all()=max(df['prev_balance'] - df['balance'],0)
```

I am new to Python and trying to replicate SAS implemented logic which, I hope, is identical to what I wrote here. All actions above can be performed 'at once' on the whole dataframe and are preparation of data to enable row-by-row iterating, so I am open to any suggestions what is unefficient or not implemented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is used to `AND` together predicates in a DataFrame select:

`df.loc[((df['seq'] > 0) & (df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days'))) , 'balance']`

Also note you have to put `()` around each predicate.

Comment: Bonus question: I need to assign to those values result of `max(df['prev_balance'] - df['balance'],0)`, but I think that it is imterpreted as aggregate function, because I get error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
Assigning only `df['prev_balance'] - df['balance']` works fine. But how to assign max of two numbers here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `&` operator for that instead of `and`:

```
df.loc[(df['seq'] > 0) & (df['bus_dt'] - df['prev_bus_dt'] <= pd.Timedelta('2 days')) , 'balance']
```